# Viewport Data on Revit File Exists but Could Not Be Found

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to use the Viewports Extension to retrieve a 3D-To-2D Matrix. This is the code I am using on my model:

```
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, sheet);
...
let viewports = viewportExt.getViewports(viewer.model);
```

The issue is that viewports will always be an empty array me despite checking the file in Revit and seeing that there are viewports in the sheet. I also tried checking the AECModelData that the Viewports Extension uses, and I found:

```
viewports: [
  ...
  {
    ...
    modelToSheetTransform: Array(12),
    sheetGuid: <Sheet Guid>,
    viewGuid: <View Guid>,
    viewType: "FloorPlan",
    viewportGuid: <Viewport Guid>,
    viewportPosition: Array(6),
    viewportRotation: 0
  }
]
```

I checked the sheet and viewport GUIDs in Revit, and they corresponded to the AECModelData.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's hard to tell with limited information.

To make the `Autodesk.AEC.ViewportsExtension` work, you need to ensure that your Floor plans fit the below conditions (see [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Design-Collaboration/files/GUID-0A824636-51A3-4EDC-8152-8D42CFF5616E-html.html) for details):

- Only support 2D sheets with floor plan views, structural plan views, or reflected ceiling plan views. Other sheets with callout or area plan views are not supported currently.
- Sheets with the [Crop View checkbox enabled](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-DocumentPresent/files/GUID-8BEBCEF0-CE2C-4635-8C7C-9D03503C0B79-htm.html) in Revit.
- Views without view breaks. Views containing view breaks or view splits are not supported currently.

Here is an example of my working viewport data

[image]